# Using CancelKeyPress event on a .NET console app

Tags: c#, console-application, cancellation, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I've written a .NET console app (in C#) on v4.5.1. My `Main` method looks like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate
                              {
                                  CancelToken.Cancel();
                              };

    var kbTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                                {
                                    while (true)
                                    {
                                        await ProcessCommand(Console.ReadLine());
                                    }
                                }, CancelToken.Token);

    kbTask.Wait(CancelToken.Token);
}
```

One of the possible commands (handled by `ProcessCommand`) invokes a long-running process which I'd like to be able to cancel using CTRL + C via the `Console.CancelKeyPress` delegate.

But when I do this Visual Studio opens a tab which says "mscorlib.dll is not loaded" and then does nothing - the console remains open but unresponsive.

I've also tried to run the app outside of debug but I can't find the executable.

Comment: You need to check the state of the cancel token within the `while` loop after break out when it's set.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you use Avast.  Uninstall it asap.

Comment: @HansPassant Your crystal ball is wrong. No AV installed other than the stock Windows Defender.

Comment: @Sean The long-running process goes through a `foreach` loop, and at the end of each pass I check the CancellationToken (which is a global).

Answer (score 0):

Goto Tools, Options, Debugging, Symbols and set a cache location. Then hit load in the above and it will fetch the necesary symbols for you and store them in the cache location you provide.

Microsoft's compiler tools create symbols in separate files with a .pdb extension (program database). This allows them to create detached symbols for release binaries. With a symbol server, your IDE can fetch the symbol file matching the specific version of the DLL during debugging. You can configure this system for your own product binaries as well which can be very useful for post-mortem debugging any crashes on end-user machines.

See [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details about using their public symbols.

Comment: Having done this, I can see the symbols being dynamically loaded, but now when I hit CTRL+C Visual Studio opens a tab which says "Source Not Available" and again the console is unresponsive.

Comment: "Source Not Available" Error occurs when the application is trying to read some un-managed code. Let me sort this out for you.